# Does anyone know if the Firefox ESR PPA is still being maintained?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

Both Thunderbird and Firefox ESR have been upgraded to Version 68 on my Windows machines a long time ago, but I still have Version 60 on Ubuntu.  PPA is https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: The last update is listed on that page for 2019-09-07 (8 weeks ago), which to me is pretty recent & a good sign of being maintained.  If you'd like more regular updates, why not take it up with the team yourself?  (*they may let you join & help with the work, however the version differences does not mean the windows is more secure - different platforms can use different releases with all security fixes applied; and more than one version has been current before now; and I assume still applies*)

Comment: This ppa offers firefox-esr. esr suffix means Extended Support Release.

Comment: The Extended Support Release version 68 is available from their direct download page, for example, https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US . If the PPA is not providing version 68 as the direct download page is, that's an issue to discuss with the package maintainer via Launchpad https://launchpad.net/~osomon

Comment: Thank you for that pointer.  I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1850064 
And added a comment regarding Firefox ESR as well

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the Ubuntuzilla repository has the latest versions of both Firefox ESR and Thunderbird, so I deleted the versions from the OP PPA and replaced them with those.  Had to move the profile files to different directories because they had different names, but that was easy enough.  All up to date the the current security patches again.